What is this aircraft from the TV series "Fear the Walking Dead"?

Still from Fear the Walking Dead of unknown cargo plane

According to the Internet Movie Plane Database, this plane is part of Ep. 5.08 Is Anybody Out There? and is a Short SC.7 Skyvan as you already found:

Approximately the same view as in your question:

Source: airliners.net, photo by Szécsi Péter.

That appears to be a Short C-23 Sherpa. Smallish cargo aircraft, operated by many entities, incl the USAF and US Army.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_C-23_Sherpa

Thanks for the help. Researching I think it's a Short SC.7 Skyvan, from the C-23 was developed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_SC.7_Skyvan

Given that image, the exact version is likely unknowable. But it is some variant of the common Skyvan platform or a derivative.

Not enough fuselage windows for a C-23, surely?

AKA, the flying Winnebago. Is that an airplane or the box it came in?

@MichaelHarvey Yeah, and IMHO more obviously the nose of the C-23 is way too pointy.

And all the way from Northern Ireland I think?

Yep, an Irish aircraft. Who knew?
